# Is it possible to declare a protocol with an associatedtype inside a protocol?

Tags: swift

I want to declare a protocol with an associatedtype inside the protocol.

I know that declaring it as a class rather than a protocol solves the problem.

But I want to use it within the protocol.

Is there a way to use a protocol with an associated type in the protocol using things like generics or typealias?

```swift
protocol A {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol B {
    var a: A { get } // error. protocol 'A' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
                     // But I want set a.T = Int
}
```

Comment: `A` in `B` can also be associated type and you can extend `B` where `A` will be another protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to set `A.T` to `Int`, you can specify that in an associated type `where` clause within B:

```swift
protocol A {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol B {
    associatedtype U: A where U.T == Int 
    var a: U { get }
}
```

Or, you do not want to lock `B` to only one particular `A.T` type, you can introduce another  `associatedtype`, which links back to `A`:

```swift
protocol A {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol B {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype U: A where U.T == T 
    var a: U { get }
}
```

See [Associated Types with a Generic Where Clause](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID557) in *The Swift Programming Language.*

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype T
    var a: T { get }
}

protocol B {
    associatedtype U where U: A
    var b: U { get }
}
```

Keep in mind though that you're gonna have to reason a lot about this because of the two associated types.